# How to write the variable s in state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

How to write the variable s in state? How to write a variable in state as the key that contains snap.key from the database?

```
componentDidMount(){ 

    let cardQuantity = firebase.database().ref("Users"); 

    cardQuantity.on('child_added',snap => { 

        let cardsValue = cardQuantity.child(snap.key); 

        let cardId = {cardId : snap.key}; 
        this.setState({cardsId : [cardId].concat(this.state.cardsId)}); 

        let s = snap.key;
        this.setState({cards : []}); 

        cardsValue.on('value',snap => { 

            snap.forEach((childSnapshot)=> { 
                let card = {text: childSnapshot.val(), id: childSnapshot.key}; 
                //   this.setState({s : [card].concat(this.state.cards)}); 
            });
        }); 
    }) 
}

<div className="Info" > 
    { this.state.cardsId.map( cardsId => <div className="Cards" key={cardsId.cardId}> 
    //    {this.state.cards.map( card => <h2 key={card.id} >
    {card.text}</h2>) } 
</div>) }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a bracket notation of the key: {[key]: value}

```
this.setState({[s] : [card].concat(this.state.cards)});
```

You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal).

Comment: this.state.cards == ?

Comment: Like here?   {this.state.cards.map( card => <h2 key={card.id} >
    { card.text } < /h2>) }

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Isn't this the question you wanted answered?

Comment: How to use in the future? I need to put the written variable here - this.state.???.map()

Comment: You can do this.state[key].map() if you have the key